# How to get a resources from a byte array or file or string or anything?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am developing a client management app that includes writing and reading various forms of documents.

Documents include contracts, terms of service, and etc.
Those documents are very dynamic and I need to be able to extract objects from documents and upload them to database.
Some document form have auto calculation functions so I need different layouts for each of them.

One of the problems is that document forms can be changed.
Though, documents that are created before the change should have a form of the created time whenever I read it.

I can upload hashmaps or json of configuration to database and mark them with version numbers but I think uploading an entire xml file is a lot easier.
Plus, uploading json files of document form can handle change of strings but it must be hard to adapt to change of layout.

So I want to store xml files of different document forms and different versions to a server and download what I need when I load a document in DocumentActivity.
And then, I want to somehow **convert the file to layout resource** and inflate a ViewStub of DocumentActivity to use it.

I can download any xml file I want and inflate a layout.
I want to know if there is anyway to inflate a layout via a byte array, string or file.

It seems very unusual thing to do so I might be doing it wrong.
If you have a better idea please let me know.

Comment: What kund of document files need a layout file? Cant you start your post explaining such?

Comment: Short answer: nope, you can't do that. Android's inflation mechanism can only be used with XML that's been processed and compiled into its packages. You can certainly download regular XML from your server, and handle the parsing and `View` instantiation yourself, but nobody ever seems to want to do that. Also, I would mention that this isn't unusual at all. It's everybody's first idea when they need to do something like this, so you might get some further ideas for solutions if you search the previous questions here.